# Защита проекта на .NET Framework

Tags: взлом, декомпиляция

Всем привет, недавно мне в скайпе добавился какой-то пользователь моей программы, и спросил на каком ЯП написана программа я ответил что на C#, он начал долго смеяться, после чего в Reflectore распотрошил мою прогу, а там внутри были параметры подключения к БД, он это всё спалил и разрушил мне проект, так вот скажите раз .NET такой хилый что почти сразу все исходники дал, может лучше с него уйти? Потому что когда я использовал .NET Reactor, он (тот кто разрушил) сказал что его этим не остановишь, и это не защита, а полная (извините за выражение) лажа. Так вот уважаемый ХешКод, помогите защитить программу, советами, названиями программ по защита и т.д очень надо, искал в Гугле там в основном всё на .NET Reactor ссылается, но говорят что его уже продырявили и его могут обойти. Как быть :=(

Comment: не стоит сваливать ваши ошибки на ошибки .NET!
вам надо переделать подключение к БД, чтобы даже зная его параметры нельзя было его повредить, а не переходить на другую платформу.

Reflector`oм легко открываются все исходники Microsoft, но они об этом почему-то не особо беспокоятся.

ИМХО, слухи о важности сокрытия кода скоих программ распростроняют только те, кто пишут говнокод

Comment: Если вы храните параметры (открыто) подключения к бд в коде то вряд ли переход на другую платформу Вам поможет

Comment: А где тогда по вашему надо их хранить?

Comment: @Merlin, это я мульт @karmadro4'а?)

Comment: "...подключения к БД в настройках хранящихся на локальном диске юзера..."

Только мне это кажется бредом?..

PS: да что-же вам всем так не угодил @karmadro4 ? Во всех бедах теперь виноват он :D

Comment: @Merlin, вы зря перетащили свою глупость про капусту из "защит" в комментарии, умнее совет не стал от этого. @Sh4dow, осторожно, он может мстительно проминусовать древние посты :-D

Comment: ну убедительных аргументов от вас не видно, а называние ответа глупостью, рассказы про анекдоты и т.п. флуд не в счет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как уже правильно тут написали, проблема не в .NET, проблема в вашем подходе к разработке.

Все предельно просто, если ваша программа удаленно взаимодействует с вашим сервером, то и специфичную логику (ту, что вы пытаетесь скрыть) нужно реализовывать на сервере, тогда не понадобится хранить никакие пароли и никакая рефлексия не поможет злоумышленнику.

Если же программа не должна взаимодействовать с вашим сервером, то не понятно зачем ей вообще какие-либо пароли от вашей БД.

Подробнее читайте про [Web Services](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0). После того, как разберетесь с ними, советую почитать про [WCF](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation).

PS Даже если бы вы писали на ассемблере и хранили пароли в зашифрованном виде - это не спасло бы вас, поскольку пароли можно вытащить из памяти в тот момент, когда они дешифруются. А декомпилировать, при необходимости, можно любую программу на любом языке.

Answer (score 4):

1. Принятой практикой является помещение параметров подключения к БД в настройках хранящихся на локальном диске юзера. В случае необходимости их надо держать в шифрованном виде
2. Принято также применять обфускацию кода.

dot NET тут не причем - это проблема касается любого языка программирования.

Если говорить конкретно о dot NET - прочитайте [статью из MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx) что надо делать чтобы защитить настройки проги

Answer (score 0):

Для начала Вам необходимо организовать самому правильную архитектуру защиты, типа  клиент-сервер.

Ну а если все же хотите защитить Ваше приложение -
[Защита .NET приложений](http://habrahabr.ru/post/106262/) статья старовата, уже наверно появилось еще что то новое.

Я для примера попробовал пропустить свою программу сразу через несколько защит, экспериментируя так, чтобы производительность не сильно падала.
После того как приложение прошло через 
    .NET Reactor

```
dotNetProtector

CodeWall

Crypto Obfuscator

The Enigma Protector

Spices.Net
```

попытка расковырять бинарник длилась долго и закончилась плачевно, конечно любую защиту можно сломать, но самое главное какую цену  (времени и сил) готов заплатить взломщик? Если Ваше приложение станет популярным его в любом случае взломают .

Рекомендую обратить внимание на [Enigma Protector](http://enigmaprotector.com/ru/home.html), довольно много вариантов защиты предлагает за умеренную цену. В паблике актуального взлома 
этого протектора на данный момент не встречал.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [**статья**](http://habrahabr.ru/post/108955/) на `Хабрахабре` о том как защитить свой код от `NET.Reflector`'а

Comment: Спасибо прочитаю.

P.s руки надо бы отбить тому кто сделал Reflector....

Comment: @Angus123, придется тогда отрубить руки и самим разработчикам .NET'а, поскольку [дизассемблер .NET-программ в MSIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.80).aspx) идет вместе с самим фреймворком.

Comment: > руки надо бы отбить тому кто сделал Reflector....

Если есть такая уверенность в своих силах, то может лучше заняться физической работой?